# how do i add an id to a div to compare it ? *(react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

when i try to add an id to a div to compare it i get an error id is not defined .

the data
[image]

the function
[image]

the div where i tried to add an id
[image]

i tried to add a key but it didn't work and the error i got was key is not defined

the id that is not defined is on the function where

id === quoteData.id

Comment: Please post code, not pictures of code...

Comment: careful, html IDs should be unique throughout the entire page. Maybe use a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) instead?

Answer (score 0):

The ID [cannot start with number](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp):

> Note: The id name must contain at least one character, cannot start with a number, and must not contain whitespaces (spaces, tabs, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

you can't start the ID with a number , if you want to compare u need to concat an character with the numbers
ex:

```
<div #id1></div>
<div #id2></div>
<div #id3></div>
```